# GmailApp and forward/reply Invoked too many times - Not clear why (plus movetoarchive not working)

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-sheets, google-apps-for-education

I am using the following two scripts to either reply to or forward emails when certain labels are applied.  I have two sheets (replySheet and forwardSheet) that hold label names in the first column.  replySheet then has the email reply text in the next cell, while forwardSheet has the email address to forward the message to.

Two questions:

- I have received the error message "Service invoked too many times for one day" for GmailApp.getUserLabelByName.  I understand that the limit for Google Apps for Education is 10,000 per day, but this code should just run every five minutes, or 288 times every day for each label. What am I misunderstanding?  Any thoughts for re-writing the code to avoid this?
- .moveToArchive() doesn't seem to do anything in replyLabel().  I've tried moving it to different points in the code (before and after sending the reply), but it doesn't archive the thread.

Thank you for any suggestions to either issue.  Please let me know if I can make my question any clearer.

```
var thisSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var forwardSheet = thisSS.getSheetByName('Forwards');
var emailSheet = thisSS.getSheetByName('Email');
var alias = emailSheet.getRange(3, 2).getValue();
var replyTo = emailSheet.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
var fromName = emailSheet.getRange(1, 2).getValue();
var replySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Replies');

function forwardLabel() {
  var data = forwardSheet.getRange(2, 1, forwardSheet.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();
  for (i in data) {   
    var row = data[i];   
    var name = row[0].toString();
    var email = row[1].toString();
    if (name && (email != "")) {
      var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(name);    
      var threads = label.getThreads(0, 100);
      for (i in threads) {
        var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
        for (j in messages) {
          Logger.log(messages[j].getSubject());
          messages[j].forward(email, {bcc:alias, from:alias, name:fromName}).markRead();
          label.removeFromThread(threads[i]);
        }
        Utilities.sleep(1000);
      }
    }
  }
}

function replyLabel() {
  var data = replySheet.getRange(2, 1, replySheet.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();
  var signature = emailSheet.getRange(4, 2).getValue().toString();
  var alias = emailSheet.getRange(3, 2).getValue();
  for (i in data) { 
    var labelName = data[i][0].toString();
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labelName);
    var replyText = data[i][1].toString();
    replyText = replyText + signature;
    if (label && (replyText !== "")) {
      var labeledEmails = label.getThreads(0, 100);
      for (j in labeledEmails) {
        labeledEmails[j].moveToArchive();
        label.removeFromThread(labeledEmails[j]);
        var messages = labeledEmails[j].getMessages();
        var message = messages[0];
        message.reply(replyText,{htmlBody:replyText, bcc:alias, from:alias, name:fromName});
        Utilities.sleep(2000);      
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just realized I haven't attributed this code, which is modified from [Digital Inspiration](http://www.labnol.org/internet/auto-forward-gmail-messages/20665/).

Answer (score 0):

How many labels do you have ? You have nested loops and the 288 gets multiplied by each loop and you could quickly be hitting the 10,000. 
Also, note that you are not counting other GMail Read operations like getTHreads() and getMessages().

If you factor in all these, you could have a number exceeding 10,000.

Comment: OK, it still doesn't seem to add up to me, but yes, the GmailApp methods inside the loops must be doing it.  Two follow-up questions: 1. How does Google count these things?  If I put the two functions in different projects, does it help?  2. Is there some way to store the value of GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(name), so that I can just call it a few times a day?  Thanks for reading and responding.

Comment: You can store the list of labels as a ScriptProperty. Some limits are per script and some limits are per account. Not sure what Gmail Read is

Comment: Thanks, @Srik. I'll try storing the labels with ScriptProperty.  Any other suggestions for cutting down on use of Gmail methods in this script?

Comment: Remove the Logger.log in forward () after you are done debugging